# Ellipis in Variadic Template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

## 1

```
template <class ...Args>
constexpr
int32_t mymin(int32_t first, Args... rest) {
    return mymin(first, mymin(rest...));
}
```

## 2

```
template <class ...Args>
constexpr
int32_t mymin(int32_t first, Args... rest) {
    return mymin(first, mymin(rest)...);
}
```

It seems like #1 looks like

```
template <class ...Args>
constexpr
int32_t mymin(int32_t first, Args... rest) {
    return mymin(first, mymin(rest0, rest1, rest2, ..., restn)); // not a valid C++ code
}
```

How about #2?  How does the "expanded" version look like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're correct on #1, #2 would expand the *full* call... `mymin(first, mymin(rest0), mymin(rest1), ..., mymin(restn))`

Comment: won't it fail to compile?  because there is no function with a signature like int32_t mymin(int32_t)?

Comment: Not with that signature, but there are functions `mymin` that can be called with one argument.

Comment: thanks for quick reply.  would you mind sharing how the signature looks like?

Comment: There's one viable `mymin` right there - the function template instantiated with an empty pack. Of course, if that's selected then you get infinite recursion...